# When can I omit "in cases"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wrote:

> For example,  <s>**in cases**</s>  where the user comments on a page are preceded by "Comments" title,  this title can be employed in an extraction rule to identify that section.

Can I use "Where" instead of "In cases where" in the sentence above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say "where" or "when".  I think "when" is preferable here, since you're talking about a *location* in the sentence ("on the page"), and thus "where" might prove confusing.

You also need an indefinite article before "Comments": *... preceded by a "Comments"  title.*

As always, brevity beckons:

If one exists on the page, a "Comments" title can be used in an extraction rule to identify that section.

Comment: Did you mean to begin the last sentence of your answer with "If"?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I corrected the typo - if you see something like that you should have enough reputation to edit it directly. Edits can always be rolled back by the author if they disagree with them. Typos can cause a lot of confusion on this site in particular, so I tried to get them resolved quickly :)

Comment: @ColleenV: Got it.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, yes you can. One of the definitions of **where** is:

> **In** a position, **case**, etc., in which:
>
> *Where ignorance is bliss, 'tis folly to be wise.*

So, **where** could mean *in cases*, so there is really no need the repitition of *in cases* in the sentence.